# ¿Cómo eliminar un elemento de un JSON en JavaScript por su clave?

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo este **JSON**

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: Mateo,
    age: 19,
    hobbies: [
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "Photography"
            description: "Photo's"
        }
        {
            id: "2",
            name: "Soccer"
            description: "Play soccer"
        }
    ]
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de eliminar un objecto del JSON por su clave?

Por ejemplo

```
delete->JSON->hobbies->name="Photography"
```

Luego de eliminar el objecto deberia quedar así:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: Mateo,
    age: 19,
    hobbies: [
        {
            id: "2",
            name: "Soccer"
            description: "Play soccer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: como deberia quedar el json luego de eliminar?

Comment: @x-rw, ya lo edité.

Comment: ¿Estás hablando de un objeto o de un string JSON? JSON != JS Object

Comment: @Pablo, de un objecto JSON.

Comment: JSON es un formato de texto para guardar información, no es un "objeto"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var jsonVar={
    id: 1,
    name: "Mateo",
    age: 19,
    hobbies: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Photography",
            description: "Photo's"
        },
      {
            id: "2",
            name: "Soccer",
            description: "Play soccer"
        }
    ]
}

console.log(jsonVar);//json original
function eliminarPorName(name){
  jsonVar.hobbies.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr){
  if(jsonVar.hobbies[index].name==name){
      jsonVar.hobbies.splice(index, index);     
   }
  })
}

eliminarPorName("Soccer");
console.log(jsonVar);//json sin su elemento
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías resolverlo usando:

- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for) y [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice)

```js
var persona = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Mateo',
  age: 19,
  hobbies: [{
    id: "1",
    name: "Photography",
    description: "Photo's"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    name: "Soccer",
    description: "Play soccer"
  }]
};

for (var i = 0; i < persona.hobbies.length; i++) {
  if (persona.hobbies[i].name == 'Photography') {
    persona.hobbies.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}
console.log(persona);
```

- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) (`IE9+`)

```js
var persona = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Mateo',
  age: 19,
  hobbies: [{
    id: "1",
    name: "Photography",
    description: "Photo's"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    name: "Soccer",
    description: "Play soccer"
  }]
};

persona.hobbies = persona.hobbies.filter(function (hobbie) {
  return hobbie.name !== 'Photography';
})
console.log(persona);
```